# Find if sum of any two columns exceed X in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Sample]. Columns are attributes, rows are observation.

I would like to extract rows, where sum of any two attributes exceed a specified value (say 0.7). Then, in two new columns, list column header with bigger and smaller contribution to sum.

I am new to python, so I am stuck proceeding after generating my dataframe.

Comment: And what if there is more than 1 combination of columns that exceeds the value for a given row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

THRESHOLD = 8.0

def valuation_formula(row):
    l = [sorted(x) for x in combinations(row, r=2) if sum(x) > THRESHOLD]
    if(len(l) == 0):
        row["smaller"], row["larger"] = None, None
    else:
        row["smaller"], row["larger"] = l[0]  # since not specified by OP, we take the first such pair
    return row  

contribution_df = df.apply(lambda row: valuation_formula(row), axis=1)
```

So that, if

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1.0, 2.0, 4.0], "b" : [5.0, 6.0, 7.0]})
     a    b
0  1.0  5.0
1  2.0  6.0
2  4.0  7.0
```

then, `contribution_df` is

```
     a    b  smaller  larger
0  1.0  5.0      NaN     NaN
1  2.0  6.0      NaN     NaN
2  4.0  7.0      4.0     7.0
```

HTH.